# How to find directory being served by Apache

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm trying to debug someone else's script. They've given me access to the server and a URL, what they didn't tell me is where their scripts are located.

**How can I find the directory that serves the URL?**

I've already checked in /var/www/ but no luck, people have been messing with the server and Apache is serving pages from many directories.

Comment: is that apache is already running??

Comment: @ambarox Yes apache is running

Comment: try >>  ps -ef | grep apache >> it will give you the currently running apache process from that you can get the location.

Comment: find  / -name "apache" >> this will give all directories with apache name or pattern.

Comment: How is it?? working??

Comment: What's with asking the responsible developer/administrator? Sounds a bit oldscool but it's often the best choice. Further: your question lacks the OS and what scripts you're looking for (PHP, CGI).

Comment: /var/www/ it is unix :D

Comment: @ambarox Thanks but those commands didn't work, they show me the apache processes but not the directories that they're serving.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I tried asking him already, but he's in another timezone and I can't be bothered to wait. I'm not sure what language the scripts are written in, the URL doesn't specify.

Comment: What about find command??

Comment: @ambarox nope, no luck there either

Comment: @Drahcir: Not knowing which scripts any answer is very speculative. If you have root access try `grep`ing for "DocumentRoot" or "ScriptAlaias" in /etc/httpd/ or /etc/apache (depending on the platform). If not: try `find`ing "cgi-bin" under /var and /usr. Common HTTP file directories are _named_ "htdocs", "www" or "www-data". **All this depends on the OS which you didn't tell us unfortunately.

Comment: @try-catch-finally The OS is Ubuntu. The files won't be in any of those standard locations, that's my problem, the standard location of "/var/www" exists, and it is serving files, just not the files I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old, but if it is ubuntu, you should look into apache config which probably has not been messed with. It's located in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Also, have a look in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for possible virtual hosts that might be serving it.

You should search for Directory, and that should tell you where the scripts are served from.